# How can I import a wsdl in Azure API Management

Tags: azure, wsdl, azure-api-management

I'll be gratefull if you can help me with the following error: When I try to import a WSDL file in Azure API management I have the next error:

WsdlImportRuleImportNotSupported : WSDL Import is currently not supported
[image: error]

Is there a way to solve it ?

thank you!

Answer (score 8):

If you look in the WSDL file you are trying to import there is a wsdl:Import element that references an external file.  We don't support importing WSDLs that are split into multiple files.  We can import eternal references XSD schemas though.

If your wsdl is coming from a later WCF service you can request the wsdl using a query parameter `?singleWSDL` and it will merge the WSDL into a single file for you.  There are also OSS tools on GitHub for doing a WSDL merge.

Comment: Thank you, I´m going to test this solution

Comment: This resolved by issue and led to a different issue.